# Android view disappears when setting layout_height to fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have list items and I want to add a rectangle that is the full height of the item to the left side of the view, this is the list item xml (sorry for weird formatting):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
android:background="@drawable/rowselector"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="5sp"
android:paddingBottom="5sp"
android:paddingLeft="10sp"
android:paddingRight="10sp">

<View
android:id="@+id/stop_color_shape"
android:background="@drawable/stop_color_shape"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/star"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


<CheckBox
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:button="@drawable/btn_star"
    android:id="@+id/star"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

When the View's (stop_color_shape)layout_height is set to 20dp, it shows, when it's set to fill_parent it doesn't

the drawable (stop_color_shape) is:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid
android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I found this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735380/android-relativelayout-fill-parent-unexpected-behavior-in-a-listview-with-varyin

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `RelativeLayout`'s height is set to `wrap_content`. Change it to `fill_parent` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Either use fillparent throughout or wrapcontent throughout just in case to avoid confusions. And to keep track of ui design